# Radio button logic with multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get table rows to show when the values in the cells match selctions made in two groups of radio checkboxes (already working).

But I now want to write multiple values in a cell (i.e. 30, 60 and 90) in the 'term' cells. The radio input should then show this row if 30, 60 or 90 is selected in the radio group 'term' so long as the 'amount' radio selection matches. This will work both ways, so there can be multiple options for both sets. (i.e. one row will show for multiple 'amounts' values and multiple 'term' values when both radio sets match at least one from each).

```js
<script>
  
  function renderLenders() {
  var amounts = $("input[name=amount]:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  var terms = $("input[name=term]:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();

  var l = lenders.filter(function(item, index, array) {
    return amounts.indexOf(item.amount) != -1;
  });

  l = l.filter(function(item, index, array) {
    return (
      (
        item.term == 30 &&
        terms.indexOf("30") != -1
      ) ||
      (
        item.term == 60 &&
        terms.indexOf("60") != -1
      ) ||
      (
        item.term == 90 &&
        terms.indexOf("90") != -1
      ) ||
      (
        item.term == 180 &&
        terms.indexOf("180") != -1
      ) ||
      (
        item.term == 360 &&
        terms.indexOf("360") != -1
      )
    );
  });

  var rows = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    rows += "<tr><td>" + l[i].name + "</td><td>" + l[i].amount + "</td><td>" + ((l[i].term > 0) ? l[i].term : "None") + "</td></tr>";
  }
  $("#lenders").html(rows);
}
$(function(){
  renderLenders();
  $("input[type=radio]").on("click", function(){
    renderLenders();
  });
})
    </script>
```

```html
<input id="100" type="radio" name="amount" value="100" checked />
<label for="100"><b>&#163;100</b></label>
<input id="250" type="radio" name="amount" value="250" />
<label for="250"><b>&#163;250</b></label>
<input id="500" type="radio" name="amount" value="500" />
<label for="500"><b>&#163;500</b></label>
<input id="1000" type="radio" name="amount" value="1000" />
<label for="1000"><b>&#163;1,000</b></label>
<input id="1500" type="radio" name="amount" value="1500" />
<label for="1500"><b>&#163;1,500</b></label>

<input id="30" type="radio" name="term" value="30" checked />
<label for="30"><b>30 days</b></label>
<input id="60" type="radio" name="term" value="60" />
<label for="60"><b>60 days</b></label>
<input id="90" type="radio" name="term" value="90" />
<label for="90"><b>3 mths</b></label>
<input id="180" type="radio" name="term" value="180" />
<label for="180"><b>6 mths</b></label>
<input id="360" type="radio" name="term" value="360" />
<label for="360"><b>12 mths</b></label>

<table>
  <tbody id='lenders'></tbody>
</table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lenders = [{
  name: "Bank 1",
  amount: "100",
  term: 30
}, {
  name: "Bank 2",
  amount: "100",
  term: 60
}, {
  name: "Bank 3",
  amount: "100",
  term: 90
}, {
  name: "Bank 4",
  amount: "100",
  term: 180
}, {
  name: "Bank 5",
  amount: "100",
  term: 360
}, {
  name: "Bank 6",
  amount: "250",
  term: 30
}, {
  name: "Bank 7",
  amount: "250",
  term: 60
}, {
  name: "Bank 8",
  amount: "500",
  term: 360
}, {
  name: "Bank 9",
  amount: "1000",
  term: 30
}, {
  name: "Bank 10",
  amount: "1500",
  term: 60
}];
```

Comment: What is your question? What does not work? What would you expect and what actually happens? Which errors do you see? Kindly provide us with details

Comment: As I say in question, the radio logic works to select a value from both sets and show a result. But I want the table data to allow for two (or more) values, so that the same row can return under different combinations of radio selections? - So how do I write the table data with multiple values in 'amount' and 'term' so the script still works correctly?

Comment: I also have a hard time figuring out what you mean, is it correct that you want to define multiple `amount` and/or `term` values in a single "Bank"-record?

Comment: yes! that's it, sorry if I am not clear. I am happy for it to change from looking at the cell values, to looking at an id or class instead if easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `terms` and `amounts` are turned into arrays, you should first declare them and then in your filter functions, you need to perform a 'sub'-filter to figure out the actual match.

I have adapted your example to what I think you ask and made this work.

```js
var lenders = [{
    name: "Bank 1",
    amount: ["100"],
    term: [30, 60]
  }, {
    name: "Bank 2",
    amount: ["250"],
    term: [60]
  }, {
    name: "Bank 3",
    amount: ["100", "250"],
    term: [30]
  }, {
    name: "Bank 4",
    amount: ["100"],
    term: [60]
  }, {
    name: "Bank 5",
    amount: ["250"],
    term: [30]
  }, {
    name: "Bank 6",
    amount: ["100", "250"],
    term: [30, 180]
  }
];


function renderLenders() {
  var amounts = $("input[name=amount]:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  var terms = $("input[name=term]:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();

  var l = lenders
    .filter(function(item, index, array) {
      return item.amount.filter(function(a) {
        return amounts.indexOf('' + a) >= 0;
      }).length;
    })
    .filter(function(item, index, array) {
      return item.term.filter(function(t) {
        return terms.indexOf('' + t) >= 0;
      }).length;
    });

  var rows = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    rows += "<tr><td>" + l[i].name + "</td><td>" + l[i].amount + "</td><td>" + ((l[i].term > 0) ? l[i].term : "None") + "</td></tr>";
  }
  $("#lenders").html(rows);
}

$(function() {
  renderLenders();
  $("input[type=radio]").on("click", function() {
    renderLenders();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="100" checked />
  <b>&#163;100</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="250" />
  <b>&#163;250</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="term" value="30" checked />
  <b>30 days</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="term" value="60" />
  <b>60 days</b>
</label>

<table>
  <tbody id='lenders'></tbody>
</table>
```

If your logic requires to show only the actual matching values, I'd change the filtering logic to first map the new values and then filter on these
For example

```
var l = lenders
  .map(function(item) {
    return {
      name: item.name,
      amount: item.amount.filter(function(v) {
        return amounts.indexOf('' + v) >= 0;
      }),
      terms: item.term.filter(function(v) {
        return terms.indexOf('' + v) >= 0;
      })
    };
  })
  .filter(function(item) {
    return item.amount.length && item.terms.length;
  });
```

I've [created a fiddle on what I would really do](https://jsfiddle.net/qm8ctp6t/), this also includes the `mapping` and reduces the amount of logic required to compare as the example makes use of radio buttons ("there can only be one" selected), so it is useless to create an array for it. Unless you're switching to `checkbox` elements, then you must resort to the use of arrays.

By now you may or may not have noticed I also touched your HTML example, here's why:

```
<input id="100" .. /><label for="100">..</label>
```

An id value cannot start with a number (so it cannot be a number), and for the demonstrated use case, it is redundant to go through lengths to apply references while it is just as easy to simply embed the `<input>` inside the `<label>` and enjoy the same interaction mechanics it offers.
The only reason (for me) to not use this approach is when the `<label>` is not anywhere near the `<input>`, then I'd link them with `id`/`for`.

Some final thoughts my (small) change to `indexOf`.

You may have noticed I write the `indexOf` logic slightly different. The `>= 0` instead of `!== -1` is a personal preference, both do the same thing. I like to think of `>= 0` as *"is it in the array?"*, while `!== -1` (to me) reads as *"is it not not in the array?"*.
I have also made sure I'm comparing to the string values (`indexOf('' + t)`), I do this because it allows me to ensure the types match (any value obtained from HTML-attributes is a (DOM)String) whilst providing the option to define them in the `lenders` as convenient as possible (numbers tend to be 2 characters shorter than strings).

Comment: Thank you. Stupid question. How to I add additional table data without having to add to the script. Why can I not just add new columns of data to the var lenders. which may include text, images, links etc?

Comment: If you're asking on how to dynamically display all properties, this is very well possible, as you can iterate over the properties using `Object.keys(item).forEach(..)` or `for (var p in item){..}`, I simply did not do this as it was not part of the question ;-)

Comment: Yeah I know sorry. I just wish I stuck to html, css where I am confortable. I hate using table data in a script :( thank you though!

Comment: I've [created a sample](https://jsfiddle.net/qm8ctp6t/2/) on how to do this, it even generates a class on each cell and a table head. Just note that this sample is not flexible in the field ordering, it just creates the heading based on the first 'record' and assumes the rest has the same structure.

Comment: That is amazing, thanks. can you add child rows to tables using the same method. I.e. a row under each 'bank' that spans the width of the parent row?

Comment: [yes you can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan). Maybe you need to open a new question for your next one ;-)